# Java GUI Temp Calculator W/Two JButtons (Cel/Fah) output of Calc in Jlabel5?

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I am trying to build a GUI Temperature calculator. I am almost certain i'm close to completion and trying to find the fix before I go looking through old code and java book. Plus maybe this will help someone in the future. I believe that my mistake took place down around the  if statement section and can only think that maybe i'm mistakingly placing things in the wrong place i.e textfield and labels.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.lang.Math;
    public class GUI implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5;
    JTextField word1;
    JButton Celcius, Fahrenheit;

    public GUI(){
    frame = new JFrame("Temperature Convertor");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    // Box layout
    //contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    //contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    //contentPane.setBackground(Color.black);

    //Grid layout
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 5));
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.black);

     label1 = new JLabel("Temperature Convertor");
     label1.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
     contentPane.add(label1);

    label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image1.jpg"));
    label2.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
    contentPane.add(label2);

    label3 = new JLabel("Enter Temperature: ");
    label3.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
    contentPane.add(label3);

    word1 = new JTextField(10);
    contentPane.add(word1);

    Celcius = new JButton("Celcius");
    Celcius.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Celcius.setActionCommand("Celcius");
    Celcius.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(Celcius);

    Fahrenheit = new JButton("Fahrenheit");
    Fahrenheit.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Fahrenheit.setActionCommand("Fahrenheit");
    Fahrenheit.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(Fahrenheit);

    label4 = new JLabel("The Coverted Temperature is: ");
    label4.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
    contentPane.add(label4);

    label5 = new JLabel("");
    label5.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    label5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,30,30));
    contentPane.add(label5);

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    String eventName = event.getActionCommand();
    if (eventName.equals("Celcius")){
        String label5;
        double word1;
        label5 = word1.getText();
        label5 = (((Double.parseDouble(word1)*9)%5)+32) + "Degree's Celcuis" 
 ; 
        label5.setText(Double.toString(word1));
    }
    else if (eventName.equals("Fahrenheit")){
        String label5;
        double word1;
        label5 = word1.getText();
        label5 = ((((Double.parseDouble(word1)-32)*5)%9)) + "Degree's    
   Fahrenheit" ;   
        label5.setText(Double.toString(word1));



        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI g = new GUI();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I believe that my mistake took place"* - I think what would be more useful is if you: 1- Describe the problem you are actually having; 2- Asked an actual question (and 3- let us know what it's currently doing and what it should be doing) - as some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here...

```
double word1;
label5 = word1.getText();
```

`double` is a primitive, it has no properties or methods, let along a `getText` method

I think what you wanted to was something more like...

```
String label5;
label5 = word1.getText();
label5 = (((Double.parseDouble(label5) * 9) % 5) + 32) + "Degree's Celcuis";
```

I have no idea what you were think when you did...

```
label5.setText(Double.toString(label5));
```

`label5` is already a `String` and `String` also doesn't have a `setText` method, so none of it makes any sense what so ever.  Maybe you meant to use `JLabel label5;` instead, which would mean you need to name your variables better

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

String eventName = event.getActionCommand();
if (eventName.equals("Celcius")){
    String label5;
    double word1;
    label5 = word1.getText();
    label5 = (((Double.parseDouble(word1)*9)%5)+32) + "Degree's Celcuis" ; 
    label5.setText(Double.toString(word1));
}
else if (eventName.equals("Fahrenheit")){
    String label5;
    double word1;
    label5 = word1.getText();
    label5 = ((((Double.parseDouble(word1)-32)*5)%9)) + "Degree'sFahrenheit" ;      
    label5.setText(Double.toString(word1));
    }   
}
```

Your mistake is here...
You declare 2 new local var, lable5 as String and word1 as double, so your previous variables (word1 as JTextFeild and lable5 as JLable) are not available here ... the double variable doesn't have getText method and String doesn't have setText.
Do something like this  :

```
   double d = Double.valueOf(word1.getText()); 
   String s  = (((d*9)%5)+32) + "Degree's Celcuis"  ; 
    label5.setText(s);
```